# IntelliJ: what is the "Select All" keybinding called?

Tags: intellij-idea

I've set emacs mode, but would like to bind command-A to "select all".  What is the name of the appropriate Editor Action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main Menu > Edit > Find > Select All

The default binding is `CTRL+X, H`.

There is also a search field at the top of the window to help track down bindings (no snark intended, mentioned just in case you might not have seen it).